# SQL update records with ROW_NUMBER()

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called 'cards', which has a column called 'position' 
How can I update/set the 'position' to equal the row number of each record, using ROW_NUMBER()?

I am able to query the records and get the correct values using this statement:

```
"SELECT *,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER () as position FROM cards"
```

So, I would like to do this but have it update the new values in the database.

Comment: sqlite doesn't support `row_Number()`, so the question only makes sense for Postgres.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Let me assume that `cards` has a primary key.  Then you can use `join`:

```
update cards c
    set position = c2.seqnum
    from (select c2.*, row_number() over () as seqnum
          from cards c2
         ) c2
    where c2.pkid = c.pkid;
```

I should note that the `over ()` looks strange but Postgres does allow it.  Normally an `order  by` clause would be included.

Comment: Just as a note, this technically *works* but finding it can create massive temp storage issues depending on size of your database.

Answer (score 12):

Original question was tagged with [**SQLite**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41069860/revisions). 
Starting from **SQLite 3.25.0** we could natively use [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://www.sqlite.org/draft/windowfunctions.html).

```
CREATE TABLE cards(pk INT PRIMARY KEY, c VARCHAR(2), seq INT);
INSERT INTO cards(pk, c) VALUES (10,'2♥'),(20,'3♥'),(30, '4♥');

WITH cte AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS rn FROM cards)
UPDATE cards SET seq = (SELECT rn FROM cte WHERE cte.pk = cards.pk);

SELECT * FROM cards;
```

[image]

Exactly the same code will work with PostgreSQL too: **[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/UEUZ67327)**

Answer (score 1):

Consider sequence solution as well. From https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/303832/58609

```sql
create sequence position_seq;
update cards  
  set position = nextval('position_seq');
drop sequence position_seq;
```