# Updating records in batches in Rails/Postgres to reduce UPDATE calls to the database?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

This feels like something that's probably relatively simple to do but I just don't know what I'm searching for.

I've got a relatively simple loop that iterates over thousands of records to assign them a "rank". A typical collection will have about 10,000 items, so running this means around 10,000 UPDATE calls to the database.

Is there a way to batch these to reduce that?

```
collection = Collection.find(collection_id)

collection.assets.order(elo_rating: :desc).each_with_index do |asset, index|
    asset.update(rank: index + 1);
end
```

Comment: If logic for calculating rank value is this simple, you should be able to update all of them in just one operation, using Postgres' [ROW_NUMBER()](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-row_number/)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41069860/sql-update-records-with-row-number and https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/137535/sort-table-rows-and-save-the-row-numbers-using-update  is the general idea

Comment: And of course a framework challenge - do you really need to store the rank? Can  you select a RANK or ROW_NUMBER instead when fetching the records?